# Create a new column based on values that start with the same pattern

Tags: r, grouping, startswith

I am trying to use the `starts_with` function in R to create a new column, `groups`, based on the values of another column, `codi`, that start with the same pattern.

So my data is such -the output is a character:

`dput (head(Despesa_2021$CODIGO, 40))`

`df <- structure(list(codi=c("01113", "01136", "01163", "01167", "0117A", "01173", "04210","04411", "04421", "04431", "04441", "04511", "04521", "02301", "03113")))`

`> df`

And I want to create a new column with intervals that group the values of `codi`such that those starting with "01" are grouped into "Group A", those starting with "02" are group into "Group B", and so on...

The new column would be such that Group A appears as many times as values in `df` start with "01", etc... Something like:

`df1 <- structure(list(groups=c("Group A", "Group A", "Group A", "Group A", "Group A", "Group A", "Group D", "Group D", "Group D", "Group D", "Group D", "Group D", "Group D", "Group B", "Group C")))`

`> df1`

Comment: Can you please use `dput(df)` to provide a reproducible dataset? Also, in your example, none of the values of `x` start with `0`.. Are you implying that x should have leading 0s?

Comment: Also, give us a clear indication of what you want the output to look like, one row per group? And be careful of data types. `starts_with` is intended to be used with strings, not numbers.

Comment: You could have a look at the `dplyr::case_when()` function.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: An even more general solution:

```
df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(two_digit = as.integer(substr(codi, 1, 2)),
         groups = paste0("Group ", LETTERS[two_digit]))  %>% 
  select(-two_digit)
```

---

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(groups = case_when(
    substr(codi, 1, 2) == "01" ~ "Group A",
    substr(codi, 1, 2) == "02" ~ "Group B",
    substr(codi, 1, 2) == "03" ~ "Group C",
    substr(codi, 1, 2) == "04" ~ "Group D"
  ))
```

Output:

```
   codi  groups 
   <chr> <chr>  
 1 01113 Group A
 2 01136 Group A
 3 01163 Group A
 4 01167 Group A
 5 0117A Group A
 6 01173 Group A
 7 04210 Group D
 8 04411 Group D
 9 04421 Group D
10 04431 Group D
```